# Using multiple audio sources for a media player in Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to create a media player with multiple sounds and play one at random when a button is clicked.
I tried using the MediaPlayer.create() function but I can only set one audio source.
I also tried using the setDataSource() function but this only seems to work for resources that are stored outside the application (as far as I know).

```
String meowsounds[] = new String[]{
                "R.raw.meowcat1",
                "R.raw.meowcat2",
                "R.raw.meowcat3",
                "R.raw.meowcat4",
                "R.raw.meowcat5",
        };
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        meow.setOnClickListener((view) ->{
            Random random = new Random();
            int r = random.nextInt(6-1) + 1;
        try{
            mp.setDataSource(meowsounds[r]);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    });
```

This code doesn't give any error while running but doesn't play anything on click

EDIT: Updated code which works on first click but not on subsequent clicks:

```
meow.setOnClickListener((view) ->{
            Random random = new Random();
            int r = random.nextInt(6-1) + 1;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Integer.valueOf(r).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try{
                if(r==1)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat1);
                else if (r==2)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat2);
                else if (r==3)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat3);
                else if (r==4)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat4);
                else
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat5);
                mp.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), fileDescriptor.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R - is the class with constants. "R.raw.meowcat1" - is the simple string and it is not constant which consider link to file.

First, you need to create int array of raw constants, but not string array of simple strings.
Second, If you want to play file from raw, you need to create AssetFileDescriptor for this raw file and use in setDataSource method. For example:

```
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat1);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), fileDescriptor.getLength());
```

And don't forget please release codec in onDestroy method.

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. I got it working with this code, however it only works on the first button click and doesn't seem to reassign on the next clicks. Any suggestion? 
Edit: updated the original question with the code because I can't fit it here